# Why is IntelliJ saying: Package secure does not exist?

Tags: java, playframework

I've setup my Play Framework 1.2.1 project to run from within IntelliJ using the instructions from the following post on Google groups:

http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/msg/54cfe212cbae218e

However, following the tutorial at http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.2/guide8, I'm getting the following error from the IDE:

```
/Library/WebServer/Documents/devschool.play/app/controllers/Security.java
package Secure does not exist
/Library/WebServer/Documents/devschool.play/app/controllers/Application.java
cannot find symbol class Secure
```

When I run the application with > play run, everything works fine, but I prefer running it from the IDE. Please note that the project was running perfectly from the IDE before I added the secure module.

Is there a way to fix this? I have a hunch it's to do with an external source, but not being a Java expert, I'm not entirely sure how to do this.

Can anyone please assist?

Comment: When unchecking "Make" in the "Before Launch" panel on the "Edit Configurations" dialog box, and the project runs in both run and debug mode, without any problems. The IDE still, however, underlines for example Secure in @With(Secure.class) with red, stating that it 'Cannot resolve symbol Secure'. How do I get them to disappear?

Comment: For me this answer made the most sense: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166860/why-is-intellij-saying-package-secure-does-not-exist/7746550#7746550

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so the project is compiling and running okay after unchecking the "Make" checkbox from the Edit Configurations dialog box.

To get the IDE to find the code, you simply need to Attach Sources. On the Mac, press Command + ; and add the sources under the Libraries section.

Answer (score 7):

You should run the following commands:

```
play dependencies
play idealize
```

The first one will resolve the dependencies from the Secure module.
The second will update the IntelliJ "classpath" and the red lines/errors regarding the Secure module will disappear.

Comment: Hmm, I ran play idealize when I first started using IntelliJ with Play!, never realized that it needs to be run again after module changes.

Answer (score 2):

From the second link you posted, there is a class called `Security`, it looks like this:

```
public class Security extends Secure.Security {

    static boolean authenticate(String username, String password) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

`Security` extends `Secure.Security`, which is another class named `Security` in the `Secure` package.  This error is saying that it cannot find the package `Secure`.  Make sure you are including everything in your classpath properly.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you run play idealize after adding modules to dependencies.yml or adding dependencies to the application.conf(which is deprecated by the way)

Answer (score 0):

Adding modules in application.conf is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. Instead use dependencies.yml and add

```
- play -> secure
```

So now my dependencies.yml looks like:

```
# Application dependencies

require:
    - play
    - play -> secure
```

I then ran:

```
play dependencies
play idealize
```

and there was a delay but eventually Intellij recognized the module.  Not sure exactly if the last commands were necessary.

(Reposting an answer by Sascha Kleiber from the relevant page of the Play tutorial: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/guide8)